# How to Sort Jekyll Post by Front Matter

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll, github-pages, liquid

how to sort posts by `order` in Jekyll liquid.

```rb
---
layout: post
title: my title
order: 1
---
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/

**Sort**
*Sort an array. Optional arguments for hashes 1. property name 2. nils order (first or last).*

Examples:

```
{{ page.tags | sort }}
{{ site.posts | sort: "author" }}
{{ site.pages | sort: "title", "last" }}
```

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

From https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/:

```
{{ site.posts | sort: "author" }}
```

I think, this should do it:

```
<!-- or + last, see above -->
{% assign sorted_posts = site.posts | sort "order" %}
<ul>
  {% for post in sorted_posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```